# Closed-form solution for a transcendental-equation with specific coefficients?

Tags: transcendental-equations

I would like to know whether there is a closed-form solution in $x$ for the equation:

\begin{align*}
&e^{-(\alpha\delta+(\gamma-\phi)\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1})x} -\frac{\alpha(r+\delta+\phi-\gamma)}{r+\alpha\delta}e^{-(r+\alpha\delta)x} - \frac{r+\alpha(\gamma-\phi-r)}{r+\alpha\delta} = 0,&
\end{align*}
with following requirements for parameter values:
\begin{align*}
0<\alpha<1\\
0<\delta<<1\\
-1<<\gamma<0\\
0<\phi<<1\\
0<r<<1\\
r>(\gamma+\phi)\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\\
and\quad x>0,
\end{align*}
where "<<" means much greater (alternatively, one may assume that $\delta < \alpha, |\gamma|<\alpha,\phi<\alpha$ and $r<\alpha$). Here, "closed-form solution" can be understood in very broad sense, meaning that all kind of special functions are allowed (to be precise, [analytic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression) for the solution would be enough). Thank you for your time.

Comment: This can't be solved exactly unless you have a general method for solving $e^x + ae^{bx} + c = 0$, because you pick your parameters to give any of those values (up to, maybe, sign). And that sounds very unlikely to have a nice expression indeed. Would you be satisfied with a good approximation, e.g. a Taylor series in one of your parameters?

Comment: Thank you Alex! In that case, I would be satisfied if there is (not too complex) good approximation.